# Finding acceleration in a pulley system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image]

In the above system, mass A is accelerating at $a$ upwards. The question then asks to find the magnitude of mass B's acceleration, in terms of $a$.

I know that throughout the massless string, the tension is the same, but since each mass is different and has different total tension forces acting on it, $3T$ for mass B and $2T$ for mass A, I am having trouble figuring out how to solve the problem.

I've tried using $2T - m_ag = a$ and $m_bg - 3T = a_b$ but that gives me too many unknowns.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to consider masses or gravity.  Simple counting will do.

If Mass A moves up 1 cm, how much string is released from the left-hand loop?

All that string goes into the right-hand loop system.  When that string is added to the right-hand loop system, how much longer can each or the three strands get?  How far does Mass B then move?

Now you know how a linear motion of A is reflected in a linear motion of B.  Velocity and acceleration are in the same ratio... (But don't forget direction!)

Comment: Then, would $a_b = 2/3 a$ ? Since 2cm of string would be added to the right-hand loop, split over 3 strands?

Comment: Minor point: accelerations are in opposite directins...

Comment: I understand that, but is $a_b = 2/3a$?

Comment: That's strange, because the original question states that $a = 4m/s^2$ and the only options for the acceleration of B given are $1.5 m/s^2$ , $2 m/s^2$ , $6 m/s^2$ and $8 m/s^2$

Answer (score 1):

I think (in such this problems) it is easier if we consider to this fact that the length of the string is constant.

[image]

If $l$ is the length of the string, then we have:
$$l=2x_A+3x_B+\textrm{constant}$$
$$\Longrightarrow\; 2v_A+3v_B=0$$
$$\Longrightarrow\; 2a_A+3a_B=0$$